# How to fix columns wrapping around the screen instead of fitting

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm writing a website and want to show a preview for an image next to a block of text using Bootstrap 4. However, when I put both in columns, they wrap around the screen resulting in a row effectively two columns tall.

I've tried removing/adding classes to the div elements (ones for centering), but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.constrain-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.container-notfull {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <br><br><br>
  <img class="d-block w-100 background-cover" src="http://placehold.it/700x500">
  <div class="container-notfull">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2>
          Summer Camps 2019
        </h2>
        <br>
        <h3>Curriculum</h3>
        <p>
          In this camp... text
        </p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center constrain-img">
        <img class="h-75 img-center" src="http://placehold.it/700x700">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center align-self-center">
        <h3>
          There will be an entertaining camp... text
        </h3>
        <h4><a href="/css/img/flyer.pdf" download>Here</a> is a download to the flyer</h4>
        <br>
        <h3>Details</h3>
        <p><b>Place:</b></p>
        <p><b>Time:</b></p>
        <p><b>Days:</b></p>
        <p><b>Price:</b></p>
        <p>Maximum of 10 people per day</p>
        <br>
        <h4>Register now</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Given that the column widths add up to 12, I would expect that they fit horizontally. However, it overflows, and wraps around to the bottom of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your image is set to `block` but you don't have a `width` set, so it will always want to be its full size.

Setting a `width: 100%` and `height: auto` to the `.img-center` image fixes that.

```
.img-center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2g0kebs4/

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.constrain-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.container-notfull {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br><br><br>
<img class="d-block w-100 background-cover" src="http://placehold.it/700x500">
<div class="container-notfull">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h2>
        Summer Camps 2019
      </h2>
      <br>
      <h3>Curriculum</h3>
      <p>
        In this camp... text
      </p>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6 align-self-center constrain-img">
      <img class="h-75 img-center" src="http://placehold.it/700x700">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-center align-self-center">
      <h3>
        There will be an entertaining camp... text
      </h3>
      <h4><a href="/css/img/flyer.pdf" download>Here</a> is a download to the flyer</h4>
      <br>
      <h3>Details</h3>
      <p><b>Place:</b></p>
      <p><b>Time:</b></p>
      <p><b>Days:</b></p>
      <p><b>Price:</b></p>
      <p>Maximum of 10 people per day</p>
      <br>
      <h4>Register now</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, hopefully it will help you. Set a width for image and

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.constrain-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.container-notfull {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-center {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br><br><br>
<img class="d-block w-100 background-cover" src="http://placehold.it/700x500">
<div class="container-notfull">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h2>
        Summer Camps 2019
      </h2>
      <br>
      <h3>Curriculum</h3>
      <p>
        In this camp... text
      </p>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6 align-self-center constrain-img">
      <img class="h-75 img-center" src="http://placehold.it/700x700">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-center align-self-center">
      <h3>
        There will be an entertaining camp... text
      </h3>
      <h4><a href="/css/img/flyer.pdf" download>Here</a> is a download to the flyer</h4>
      <br>
      <h3>Details</h3>
      <p><b>Place:</b></p>
      <p><b>Time:</b></p>
      <p><b>Days:</b></p>
      <p><b>Price:</b></p>
      <p>Maximum of 10 people per day</p>
      <br>
      <h4>Register now</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```